# How many layers in MVVM project

Tags: mvvm

Layers in MVVM 
**How many layers in MVVM project and what we put in each layer ?
Do we have Poco also ?**

Comment: [The Answer is 42](http://hitchhikers.wikia.com/wiki/42)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three layers
Model (Data base)
View-Model (Methodes proprites commands )
View the UI without a behind code all code is in View Model

Answer (score 1):

This MSDN paper on MVVM should answer your question with regard to the logical layering of an MVVM solution. Pocos may exist depending upon your Model complexity.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx